# Dell Equallogic pseudo-syslog parser

Tags: logging, logstash, syslog, logstash-grok

I am dealing with some Dell Equallogic DAS and centralizing the logs on my ELK stack. The problem is that Equallogic logs are "syslog" ones but it seems that they don't follow the standard.

Here you have some examples of the message field:

```
<134>1130040:274:netmgtd: 9-Sep-2016 09:44:24.600275:rca_ocp.c:2137:AUDIT:myUser:25.7.14:GUI: Account USER logged in from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, using local authentication. User privilege is group-admin.
<134>1130040:274:netmgtd: 8-Sep-2016 09:44:24.600275:rca_ocp.c:2137:AUDIT:myUser:25.7.14:GUI: Account USER logged in from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, using local authentication. User privilege is group-admin.
<12>1127894:1029550:MgmtExec: 8-Sep-2016 00:00:00.026477:DefaultSnapshotSchedule.cc:902:WARNING::8.3.65:Free space is below threshold of 15 percent for pool default. Default Snapshot Schedule will run with max-keep set to 1.
```

Does anyone has a parser for this or knows the best way to parse it?
Or, what's the meaning of the `rca_ocp.c:2137`? For me sounds like a reference to a class and a line.

So far, this is the expression that I have for this:

```
%{SYSLOG5424PRI:syslog_pri}%{SYSLOGPROG:syslog_program}%{SPACE}%{EQLDATE:timestamp}:%{JAVAFILE:unknownInfo}:%{INT:unknownInt}:%{WORD:severity}:%{GREEDYDATA:message}

EQLDATE %{MONTHDAY}-%{MONTH}-%{YEAR}%{SPACE}%{TIME}
```

I choose `JAVAFILE` just as a random string, I know it is not.

Any help or suggestion is very welcome!

Comment: Your grok pattern is good (as far I can see). For "rca_ocp.c:2137", I think it's for a file rather than a class. Perhaps you can find more information with dell directly

Comment: Yep, thanks! Let's see if anyone knows here and if not, I'll check with Dell and post the answer (if given)

Answer (score 0):

Dell on its official documentation defines it as [Member on which the event occurred](http://psonlinehelp.equallogic.com/en/V6.0/groupmanager.htm)

These are nothing but c files, for example, in the following event `logevent.c` is responsible for the event,

```
351:0:logevent:24-Oct-2013 08:36:25.470001:logevent.c:242:WARNING:25.3.0:User has initiated a clean halt restart.
```

You used `JAVAFILE` which seems to be fine. This is the beauty of grok, not everything has to have a pre-defined pattern, you can simply create a custom pattern using regex and add it into pre-defined patterns.